# Weird appending to Json in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, io

I need to append a new line in 9000 json files, so, i want to automate that. And i need to put the new line between the "name" and "description", but every time i try to do it, it give me a weird result.

[sample file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e3_J8qyqV1ec2Co4T6QKVkH342I9JoYo/view?usp=sharing)

Tried to search how to do it but i don't get any good result.

[image]

[image]

Comment: please add some sample data of you json files

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to do a `json.dumps()` and `json.loads()`, after modifying it?

Comment: Using `file.write()` will never insert anything into a file, only overwrite contents. You need to read the whole file, using `json.load()` to decode it and insert your data as a new key and use `json.dump()` to write the whole file out again.

Comment: How are you getting `56`?  `strlen("{\n    \"tokenId\": 1,\n    \"name\": \"a 1\",\n")` is less than that.

Comment: The fact that it overwrote "description" means you didn't get your offset right. But you can't use offsets safely with non-binary files in python anyway. You could open binary, seek to the position you want to insert, and assuming N bytes to insert, you need to copy the entire rest of the file forward N bytes, then go back and copy your stuff. Its tricky and very fragile. json.load then add then json.dump is much easier and safer.

Comment: https://onlinegdb.com/c21fAP86R; `strlen("{\n    \"tokenId\": 1,\n    \"name\": \"a 1\",\n") = 39`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

Basicly, i understood that i can store all lines inside an list, and rewrite the file.

Now, i open the file, store the data, add my text from an string to my list, and rewrite the file with the text.

```
# The files i need to work with have numbers as names
# it make the process easy 
fileIndex = 1 


# We will use that number in the string Nlink
Number = 1


while fileIndex < 6 :

# Formated strings cant be used directly on list
NLink = f'    "Link" : "https://Link_placeHolder/{Number}.jpg",\n'

# Link stores the data, and we can use this on our list
Link = NLink


# Openning your file for reading to store the lines
with open(f"C:\\Cteste\\Original\\{fileIndex}.json", "r+") as f:
    
    # Create an list with all string information of the file
    lines = f.readlines()


    # Open a new file for writing 
    with open(f"C:\\Cteste\\New\\{fileIndex}.json", "w")as f2 :

        
        # Insert the link at especifc position in the list
        # in my case  index 2
        lines.insert(2, Link)


        # Write everything on the file, them close the files
        for i in lines :
            f2.write(i)


# add to index
fileIndex += 1

# add to number
Number += 1
```